# PHP ERROR Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function lista() on null

Tags: php, poo

Estoy trabajando un proyecto en php con MVC, sin embargo cuando trato de pasar una variable del controlador a la vista ocurre esto:
***Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function lista() on null***

Ya revisé pero no entiendo cuál es el problema, ¿cómo debo llamar la función desde la vista?

Si no la declaro así desde la vista ni me reconoce la variable de listaProductos, por lo que no puedo aplicar el foreach.

**Controlador:**

```
<?php

include('../model/productos-model.php');

class Productos{
    public $productosModel;
    public  function __construct(){              
        $productosModel = new productos_model(); 
    }


    public function listar(){
        $listaProductos = $this -> productosModel -> lista();
        echo $listaProductos;

        include_once('../views/productos.php');

        return array("listaProductos", $listaProductos);

    }
}
?>
```

**Vista:**

```
<?php
include('template/header.php');

require('../controller/productos_controller.php');

$productos = new Productos();

$listaProductos = $productos -> listar() ;

?>

<table id="tablaProductos">
<thead>
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Referencia</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio</th>
      <th scope="col">Peso</th>
      <th scope="col">CategoriaID</th>
      <th scope="col">Stock</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha creación</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha última venta</th>
      <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
foreach($listaProductos as $p){ ?>
<tr>

      <td></th>
      <td ></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></th>
      <td></th>
      <td></th>
      <td></th>
      <td></th>
      <td></th>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php include('template/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: En el constructor debería ser **`$this->productosModel = new .....`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te da nulo por qué la propiedad **`productosModel`** no es la que está recibiendo como valor la instancia de la clase.

Entonces debería alcanzar dejando esto en el constructor:

```
$this->productosModel = new productos_model();
```